# percorrer array map e encontrando as letras

Tags: node.js, cron

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação nodejs com cron job e estou precisando passar a configuração da tarefa por input para a tarefa. Então pensei em um padrão para colocar nesse input, exemplo:

```
10S:3M:2H:1D:6Y:2W
10S:3M
6Y:8T:2W
```

S => segundos, M => minutos, H => horas, D=> dias, Y=> meses, W => semanas

A´estou usando o ':' como separador dessas condições e utilizo o split para quebrar em array e map para me dar os valores separados. O que não estou conseguindo é identificar as variadas possibilidades das letras e montar o schedule cron.

```
    let input = "10S:3M:2H:1D:6Y:2W";
let spl   = input.split(':');
let newSchedule = '';

spl.map( ( item ) => { 
     if( item.chartAr( item.length - 1 ) === "S"){

        newSchedule = '"*/' + item.substring( 0, ( item.length - 1 ) ) + ' * * * * *"';

     }
     return newSchedule;

});
```

aí eu passaria newSchedule já pronta para o cron

```
cron.schedule( newSchedule ) .....
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: O que você esperava de saída com a entrada do exemplo?

Comment: @DanielMendes na variavel input eu coloquei todas as possibilidades, mas não vai ser todo caso que terão elas, pode ser que tenha so duas condições 10S:3M ou tres 10S:3M:2H etc. Mas quero que ao receber esse input ele seja separado de acordo com o padrão do cron.schedule, que ficaria assim com os valores do input separados cron.schedule("*/10 */3 */2   */1 */6 *2" ) e ficar armazendos na variavel newSchedule

Comment: @DanielMendes mas o problema quando vier dois somente 10S:3M ele teria que ser montado assim cron.schedule("*/10  */3 * * * * *" ) e ficar os astericos onde não tem valor. Cada asterisco corresponde a um tempo, segundos, minutos, dias, etc.... essa logica que não estou conseguindo encontrar